# Creating a method and returning object

Tags: java

I am extremely stuck on this assignment I have, this is the last part of the assignment and it is going over my head. We were given this code to start off with.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestEmployee2
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Employee e1 = new Employee2(7, "George Costanza");

    e1.setDepartment("Front Office");
    e1.setPosition("Assistant to the Traveling Secretary");
    e1.setSalary(50000.0);
    e1.setRank(2);

    e1.displayEmployee();

    //Employee e2 = createEmployeeFromFile();
    //e2.displayEmployee();

  }

}
```

We were told to create a method called createEmployeeFromFile();. In this method we are to read from a .txt file with a Scanner and use the data to create an Employee object. Now I am confused on two things. First on the method type I should be using, and how to create an object with the data from the .txt file. This is the first time we have done this and it is difficult for me. Employee1 works fine, but when trying to create my method I get stuck on what to create it as.

Here is my rough draft code for right now.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestEmployee2
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    EckEmployee2 e1 = new EckEmployee2(7, "George Costanza");
    EckEmployee2 e2 = createEmployeeFromFile();

    e1.setDepartment("Front Office");
    e1.setPosition("Assistant to the Traveling Secretary");
    e1.setSalary(50000.0);
    e1.setRank(2);

    e2.setNumber();
    e2.setName();
    e2.setDepartment();
    e2.setPosition();
    e2.setSalary();
    e2.setRank();

    e1.displayEmployee();
    e2.displayEmployee();
  }

  createEmployeeFromFile(){
    File myFile = new File("employee1.txt");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(myFile);

 }
}
```

I am not expecting to get the answer just someone to point me in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code from my main class.

```
public class EckEmployee2 {

 private int rank;
 private double number;

 private double salary;
 private String name;

 private String department;
 private String position;

 public EckEmployee2() {
  number = 0;
  name = null;
  department = null;
  position = null;
  salary = 0;
  rank = 0;
 }

 public EckEmployee2(double number, String name) {
   this.number = number;
   this.name = name;
 }

 public EckEmployee2(double number, String name, String department, String position, double salary, int rank) {
  this.number = number;
  this.name = name;
  this.department = department;
  this.position = position;
  this.salary = salary;
  this.rank = rank;
 }

 public void setNumber(double num) {
  this.number = num;
 }

 public double getNumber() {
  return this.number;
 }

 public void setName(String nam) {
  this.name = nam;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 public void setDepartment(String dept) {
  this.department = dept;
 }

 public String getDepartment() {
  return this.department;
 }

 public void setPosition(String pos) {
  this.position = pos;
 }

 public String getPosition() {
  return this.position;
 }

 public void setSalary(double sal) {
  this.salary = sal;
 }

 public double getSalary() {
  return this.salary;
 }

 public void setRank(int ran) {
  this.rank = ran;
 }

 public int getRank() {
  return this.rank;
 }

 public boolean checkBonus() {
  boolean bonus = false;

  if (rank < 5) {
   bonus = false;
  } else if (rank >= 5)
   bonus = true;
  return bonus;
 }

 public void displayEmployee() {
  if (checkBonus() == true) {
   System.out.println("-------------------------- ");
   System.out.println("Name: " + name);
   System.out.printf("Employee Number: %09.0f\n" , number, "\n");
   System.out.println("Department: \n" + department);
   System.out.println("Position: \n" + position);
   System.out.printf("Salary: %,.2\n" , salary);
   System.out.println("Rank: \n" + rank);
   System.out.printf("Bonus: $\n", 1000);
   System.out.println("-------------------------- ");
  } else if (checkBonus() == false)
   System.out.println("--------------------------");
   System.out.println("Name: " + name);
   System.out.printf("Employee Number: %09.0f\n" , number, "\n");
   System.out.println("Department: " + department);
   System.out.println("Position: " + position);
   System.out.printf("Salary: %,.2f\n" , salary);
   System.out.println("Rank: " + rank);
   System.out.println("-------------------------- ");
 }
}
```

To make things more clear here are the directions

> Create a method in TestEmployee2 called createEmployeeFromFile() that will read data from a file and create, populate and return an Employee object.   The file it will read from is called employee1.txt, which is provided.  Hard code the name of the file in the method.  This file contains the employee’s number, name, department, position, salary and rank. Create a Scanner object and use the Scanner class’s methods to read the data in the file and use this data to create the Employee object.  Finally return the employee object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: You should start by reading the documentation of the SCanner class, to understand how it works and how you can use it. Then read the file to see how to best read what it conains using the methods that the Scanner has

Answer (score 0):

In java, to return a value from a method, you add that objects type into the method signature as below, and in short java method signatures are as follows

'modifier (public, private, protected)' 'return type (void/nothing, int, long, Object, etc...' 'methodName(name the method)' 'parameters (any object or primitive as a parameter'

The method below will work if you have an employee contstructor which parses the input text, and assuming the data is split my a delimiter, you can use String.split(splitString); where splitString is the character that splits the data, i.e) a comma ",".

```
public EckEmployee2 getEmployee()
{
    try
    {
        /**
         * This will print where your java working directory is, when you run the file
         *
         */
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        /**
         * Gets the file
         */
        File myFile = new File("employee1.txt");
        /**
         * Makes the scanner
         */
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(myFile);

        /**
         * A list to store the data of the file into
         */
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        /**
         * Adds all the lines in the file to the list "lines"
         */
        while (kb.hasNext())
        {
            lines.add(kb.next());
        }

        /**
         * Now that you have the data from the file, assuming its one line here, you can parse the data to make
         * your "Employee"
         */

        if (lines.size() > 0)
        {
            final String line = lines.get(0);
            return new EckEmployee2(line);
        }
    }
    /**
     * This is thrown if the file you are looking for is not found, it either doesn't exist or you are searching
     * in the wrong directory.
     */
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /**
     * Return null if an exception is thrown or the file is empty
     */
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I see I was not specific, we have not learned Lists or Arrays(they are the next chapter). But I see how this works otherwise.

Comment: Check out Arrays#copy

Answer (score 0):

First your method `createEmployeeFromFile()` must take **2 parameters**, a `Scanner` object to read input, and the `File` you're gonna be reading from using the `Scanner`.

The **return type** is `Empolyee2` because the method creates a `Employee2` instance and must return it.

Now, I gave you the initiatives.
Your turn to read more about `Scanner` object and `File` object.

Reading from the text file, the attributes of your object, is easy then you create an instance by using the constructor with the attributes and return it!

Hope this helps.